# Align GXT form:FieldLabel with its gwt:Label widget

Tags: java, gwt, field, gxt

GXT 3.x only.

Let us say I wish to create a gxt field-pair of the layout

> label: value

For example,

> Name:  Carthyguessue

Where "Carthyguessue" is a constant field not updateable by user, which I effect with using a gwt:Label.

Hence the ui template:

```
<form:FieldLabel ui:field="nameLabel" text="Name" labelWordWrap="false">
  <form:widget>
     <g:Label ui:field="nameValue" />
  </form:widget>
</form:FieldLabel>
```

However, as everyone having done this realises that there would be a deficit of ~3px between the vertical offsets of nameLabel and nameValue.

One suggested approach was to [hijack the gwt-Label css](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?245338-FieldLabel-and-Alignment) to define the offset. However, what if I cannot do that because CSS is totally done by another dept.

Hence, I found this to work.

```
<form:FieldLabel text="Name" labelWordWrap="false">
  <form:widget>
    <container:VerticalLayoutContainer>
      <g:Label height="3px"/>
      <g:Label ui:field="nameValue" />
    </container:VerticalLayoutContainer>
  </form:widget>
</form:FieldLabel>
```

**My question**:

- What problems/issues would I face with this approach? (which I have yet to be aware of).
- Is there a better non-css solution?
- Ok, less importantly, why gxt folks wouldn't provide a matching Label widget (Without annoying boundaries simulated by disabled greyed-out text field), in that we still have to use gwt:Label for this purpose?

Answer (score 2):

1) better way is to create custom CSS class and asign a name to `<g:Label ui:field="nameValue" />` so in future it will easy to change.

2) No there is no other good solution. because it is a CSS issue so you have to solve it via CSS. You should create your own widget for this.

Label widget in GWT simply renders as a DIV not as a HTML's label element causing it to be displayed with block layout.